# What implications do reduce_zero_label and ignore_label have in mmseg database configuration?

Tags: python, database, configuration, semantic-segmentation

I am currently training a semantic segmentation model in a database with 3 classes: background, classA and classB. Background class is represented as [0,0,0] (value 0 in annotation image), classA is [0,255,0] (value 1 in annotation image) and classB is [0,0,255] (value 2 in annotation image).

While configuring the database parameters, I did not understand the purpose and implications of reduce_zero_label and ignore_label parameters.

If reduce_zero_label = True, is background class omited? If reduce_zero_label = True and ignore_label = 0 does it have some implication to classA and classB? Does my number of classes change or it remains 3 regardless of the value of these parameters? What effect do these parameters have on the classes?

I have trained my dataset with reduce_zero_label = True and ignore_label = 0, but the results were not as good as I imagine. So I would like to fully understand these concepts, to track down the possible error.